# AFNetworking 2 empty POST response but no errors

Tags: ios, ios8, afnetworking

It's a very tricky problem:

I do a POST request (login) to a server.

The server will answer:

- ok Status Code: 200 + JSON Data
- error Status Code: 401 + plain/text

Code:

```
func login (id: String, password: String){

    self.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
    self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =  nil
    self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(index: 400)
    //self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = nil

    var param = ["id": lbid, "password": password]

    POST(APIURL.URL_LOGIN, parameters: param,

       { (operation : NSURLSessionDataTask!, response : AnyObject!) -> Void in
            //var finalResponse : Dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
            var tmp = response as String

            self.defaults.setObject(tmp, forKey: "USERSSID")
            self.defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "USERLOGGEDIN")

            println("Success login")

        }) { (operation : NSURLSessionDataTask!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

            println(error)
    }
}
```

It executes the failure blog and I get this error:

```
    Code=-1011 "Request failed: no error (200)" UserInfo=0x7f9fa1534760 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9fa15791e0> { URL: https://************ } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Length" = 107;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Wed, 04 Mar 2015 21:47:51 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=7, max=150";
Server = Apache;
"Set-Cookie" = "SID=************; expires=Mon, 02-Mar-2020 21:47:51 GMT; path=/;domain=.*********";}},NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://***********,com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=< CORRECT POST BODY>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: no error (200)}
```

If I delete this code:

```
self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(index: 400)
```

Then the app crashes. However the server responses with status code 200...

I don't know how to solve this issue.
Could you help me?
Here I get the correct body. But why not in the normal success blog?

EDIT:

```
    self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(index: 200)
```

=> App crashs

```
    self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = nil
```

=> App crashs

```
    self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(index: 401)
```

=> App doesn't crash, but executes failure block. Status code in error message is 200 and error data contains the correct POST response body. 
=> I could extract the message from the error data... but it's such a simple task. It has to work correctly.

Can't use Alamofire because I want to use ssl certificats!

Final edit:
Don't no why, but the error disappeared by its own.

Comment: have you tried self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(index: 200)

Comment: Please post the exception that is causing your app to crash. Most likely you want something in the 2xx range, not the 4xx range.

Comment: app crash:
swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional

Comment: tried:
self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(index: 200)
=> app crashs

Comment: If you're using Swift, it may be better to use a native Swift networking library, like Alamofire (by the same author as AFNetworking) unless you need a feature that AFNetworking has but Alamofire doesn't. https://github.com/alamofire/alamofire

Comment: I need ssl connection, thats not implemented in Alamofire....

Comment: Alamofire supports HTTPS, but doesn't have the pinning or cert verification features of AFNetworking.

Comment: We use self signed certificates, that's why we can't use Alamofire. It's a not supported feature.

Comment: "acceptableStatusCodes:

The acceptable HTTP status codes for responses. When non-nil, responses with status codes not contained by the set will result in an error during validation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, check out [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) (a Google Chrome app).  That's the best way to debug AFNetworking issues, by simulating the same request and making sure the data is coming through properly.  A number of times, I've been fighting an issue to then use Postman and discover that it's something the server is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that said:

> acceptableStatusCodes
>
> The acceptable HTTP status codes for responses. When non-nil,
>   responses with status codes not contained by the set will result in an
>   error during validation.

In Objective C:

```
self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 100)];
```

Comment: But I set it nil so every status code should work for every status code?!
Even if I set it to 200, the failure blog will be executed.

Comment: My understanding is that anything set as an "acceptableStatusCode" will not execute the failure block (it is "block", not "blog")

Comment: Using this line of code:
self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(200, 100))
=>  "Swift dynamic cast failed"

using this line of code:
self.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(400, 100)) 

Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: no error (200)" UserInfo=0x7f87096077f0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f87095c51c0> { URL: ***** } { status code: 200, headers {...


Status code is 200, why doesn't afnetworking accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The previous post was very useful to fix it. I was searching more and more but nothing was helped out. I tried of adding different codes and got tired ton's of times. Finally seen the above post, which was really solved the issue. I spent 2 days to find the solution.
Initially got the error with -1011 with 400 error. I solved by using the below:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:400];
```

Again got different error like this: "200 no error". I solved by using below code:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 100)];
```

It works!! cool!!

Hence, I advice you you guys to add the set of below code:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:400];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 100)];
```

Thanks Stackoverflow!!!!